# How is possible to have EditItemTemplate and ItemTemplate at same time on Formview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, formview

I have the following inside a formview, I want to be able to show the information and if anyone makes changes I should update this information by clicking on update.I am fairly new to asp.net development , how can I do it? I keep having exception, saying frm1 is expecting editmode.

Thanks in advance

```
<<asp:Formview D="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDesc" ID="frm1">
   <ItemTemplate>
        <table>  
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:<br />
            </td>
            <td style="">
                <asp:TextBox ID="DescTbox" runat="server" Width="450px" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Enabled="True" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>                 
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
           <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"> </asp:Button>
        </td>                 
        </tr>
    </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
     <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Description:<br />
            </td>
            <td style="">
                <asp:TextBox ID="DescTbox" runat="server" Width="450px" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>' Enabled="True" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>                 
            </td>                
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
           <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"> </asp:Button>
        </td>                 
        </tr>
    </table>

    </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:Formview>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<Itemtemplate>` should provide a read only view of the data if possible, with the Update only being available in the `<EditItemTemplate>`.  You then need to put the row into edit mode to be able to edit a row by setting the `EditRowIndex` on the table.

Comment: sorry can you give any example?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `DefaultMode` as Edit and use `EditItemTemplate` instead of `ItemTemplate`

```
 <asp:Formview ID="FormView1" runat="server" DefaultMode="Edit" > 
        <EditItemTemplate> ...
        </EditItemTemplate>  <asp:Formview>
```

Thanks